# Are `thenRunAsync(...)` and `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { ... });` related at all?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

I need to perform some extra tasks but let the original thread finish up, *e.g.* send back an HTTP response.

I think I can just do this:

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenApply(response -> {
  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    // extra tasks
  });
  return response;
});
```

But I remembered there's a `thenRunAsync`. Is

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenApply(response -> {
  return response;
}).thenRunAsync(() -> {
  // extra tasks
});
```

basically another way to do the same thing? In other words, are the `then*Async` methods terminators (completion methods) that return the previous chain's result in the original thread, then spawn a new thread to execute the rest?

I'm almost certain the answer is **no**. It just *seems* it might be that purely based on method names, to someone new to CompletableFutures. I wanted a confirmation though, in case what I'm reading about `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` *is* actually saying what I'm doubting, just in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> It just ∗seems* it might be that purely based on method names, to someone new to CompletableFutures.

Well, the method names correctly reflect what the methods do. Both, `runAsync` and `thenRunAsync` initiate the asynchronous execution of a `Runnable` and return a future, which will be completed when the asynchronous execution has finished. So the similarity in the names is justified.

It’s *your* code which is fundamentally different.

In this variant

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenApply(response -> {
  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    // extra tasks
  });
  return response;
});
```

you are ignoring the future returned by `runAsync` entirely, so the future returned by `thenApply` will be completed as soon as the asynchronous operation has been triggered. The caller can retrieve the result value while the “extra tasks” are still running concurrently.

In contrast, with

```
    return mainTasksFuture.thenApply(response -> {
        return response;
    }).thenRunAsync(() -> {
      // extra tasks
    });
```

the `thenApply` is entirely obsolete as it doesn’t do anything. But you are returning the future returned by `thenRunAsync`, which will be completed when the asynchronous execution of the `Runnable` has finished and has the type `CompletableFuture<Void>`, as the runnable does not produce a value (the future will be completed with `null`). In the exceptional case, it would get completed with the exception of `mainTasksFuture`, but in the successful case, it does not pass through the result value.

If the first variant matches your actual intention (the caller should not depend on the completion of the extra tasks), simply don’t model them as a dependency:

```
mainTasksFuture.thenRunAsync(() -> {
    // extra tasks
});
return mainTasksFuture; // does not depend on the completion of extra task
```

Otherwise, stay with variant 2 (minus obsolete things)

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenRunAsync(() -> {
  // extra tasks
}); // depends on the completion of extra task but results in (Void)null
```

if you don’t need the result value. Otherwise, you can use

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenApplyAsync(response -> {
    // extra tasks
    return response;
}); // depends on the completion of extra task and returns original result
```

it would be the same as with

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenCompose(response ->
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // extra tasks
    }).thenApply(_void -> response));
```

which does not ignore the future returned by `runAsync`, but there’s no advantage in this complication, compared to `thenApplyAsync`.

Another alternative would be

```
return mainTasksFuture.whenComplete((response,failure) -> {
    if(failure == null) {
        // extra tasks
    }
});
```

as the future returned by `whenComplete` will get completed with the original future’s result when the extra tasks have been completed. But the function is always evaluated, even when the original future completed exceptionally, so it needs another conditional if that’s not desired.

Answer (score 1):

Both `runAsync` and `thenRunAsync` execute the `Runnable` taks asynchronous

> executes the given action using this stage's default asynchronous execution facility

**Question :** In other words, are the then*Async methods terminators (completion methods) that return the previous chain's result in the original thread, then spawn a new thread to execute the rest?

**Answer:** No, From documentation **One stage's execution may be triggered by completion of a single stage, or both of two stages, or either of two stages**.So basically the result might be returned based on how programmer coded that part, but now in your case (using `thenRunAsync`) the result will be returned after first stage completion because in the second stage `thenRunAsync` you are taking result from first stage as input but not returning anything.

[Interface CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html)

> One stage's execution may be triggered by completion of a single stage, or both of two stages, or either of two stages. Dependencies on a single stage are arranged using methods with prefix then. Those triggered by completion of both of two stages may combine their results or effects, using correspondingly named methods. Those triggered by either of two stages make no guarantees about which of the results or effects are used for the dependent stage's computation.

There is also a slight difference between first example and second example

**Example : 1** In this example the `Runnable` tasks get executed asynchronously before returning the result, both `Function` from `thenApply` and `Runnable` from `runAsync` will be executed concurrently

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenApply(response -> {
 CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
   // extra tasks
   });
  return response;
 });
```

**Example : 2** In this example `Runnable` task from `thenRunAsync` will be executed after completion of `Function` from `thenApply`

```
return mainTasksFuture.thenApply(response -> {
return response;
}).thenRunAsync(() -> {
  // extra tasks
});
```